# Create column in dataframe in R that shows progressive tally

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, count

I have a data frame in R that I'm attempting to create a column that tallies ascending starting at zero up to the max count for that individual.

I use the following code in R to structure my data into a dataframe then attempt to create a "count up" column. My code, however, is creating a single tally not a sequence and it is returning multiple rows, not grouped, for the same record.

```
ncUseData <- select(rollData, session, UID, name)

ncUseData <- ncUseData %>% group_by(session, UID) %>% mutate(countUp = n())
```

My expected results I'm hoping to look like this. I'm hoping to get a sequence of increasing counts.

```
session, UID, name, countUp
80, aa52, bob, 0
81, aa52, bob, 1
82, aa52, bob, 2
83, aa52, bob, 3
84, aa52, bob, 4
85, aa52, bob, 5
10, x87y, jill, 0
11, x87y, jill, 1
12, x87y, jill, 2
13, x87y, jill, 3
14, x87y, jill, 4
15, x87y, jill, 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `dplyr::row_number()`:

```
ncUseData <- ncUseData %>% 
  group_by(UID, name) %>% 
  arrange(session) %>% 
  mutate(countUp = row_number() - 1)
```

Comment: I think you need `mutate(countUp = row_number() - 1)` to have it tally "starting at zero up"

Comment: Yeah you're right I missed the part where they wanted it to start at 0.

Comment: Fantastic! It worked.  The only thing I had to change was the "mutate" to explicitly call dplyr. Thank you!
```dplyr::mutate(countUp = row_number() - 1)```